# Computer not suspending when inactive in the main log-in prompt

Tags: power-management, suspend, lock

My computer is set to automatically dim the screen and lock after 10 minutes, and suspend after an hour of inactivity.

That works fine - but only once I've logged in.

If I switch the computer on and then leave it, it won't **suspend**, although it will dim the screen.

Why does this happen, and is it a bug?

Relevant information:

- desktop computer
- mobo: M5A97 EVO R2.0
- proc: AMD FX-8320
- graphics: AMD Radeon HD 7790

Filed a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1377820.

Comment: is this a laptop or desktop ?

Comment: @Xieerqi edited the relevant information (it's a desktop)

Comment: OK, one more question. Do you have dconf editor? if not, can you please install that. 'sudo apt-get install dconf-editor '. Once you got it, open and go to the drop-down menu, click find, and type 'unity-greeter' (assuming that you didn't change your greeter/login screen). There should be a line saying idle-timeout. Can you tell me what that value is set to?

Comment: Ignore the previous comment, see my posted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

1. Install **powernap**. You can find it through Ubuntu Software Center or do `sudo apt-get install powernap` .
2. Enter terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and navigate to /etc/powernap (`cd /etc/powernap`). There you should find config file. Open it with the text editor of your choice. For me it's nano. `sudo nano config`. Or you can edit it directly as soon as you open command line - `sudo nano /ect/powernap/config`.
3. Find this portion of the file:

   [image]

   This is the copy of my edited config file. I've already set this to 1 (which is suspend). By default it is set to 0 (powersave). This setting will make computer suspend if all the things that powernap monitors are idle, in particular keyboard.
4. Bellow this portion of the config file, find next portion:

   [image]

   Again, this is copy of my already edited file. I've set ABSENT_SECONDS to 1800, because 1800 seconds is 30 minutes. Set this to your desired number of minutes. Save and close the file.
5. Navigate to /etc/default and locate powernap file.  Again, open it with text editor of your choice. `sudo nano powernap` . You're supposed to see this:

   [image]

   Again, this is copy of what I already edited. By default START=no, so set it to yes.
6. Reboot to let all the changes take effect.

   Once the login shows up, see it puts your computer to sleep without loging in.

## What I've found during research

Apparently, before Ubuntu 11 or 12.04, there used to be an app called gnome-power-manager, and there existed some solutions to this problem but this app is now depreciated. This bug , particularly for lightdm desktop, has been reported many times, but I've found no simple solution listed anywhere. I've also found that there are some ways to make gdm greeter/login screen to suspend when no one is logged in. Obviously, some people may be stubborn and stick with the default unity greeter, so this solution should work for everyone, regardless of the greeter used (I personally use gdm and unity, interchangeably).  I'm sure there are work around to this through bash scripting , but at least I couldn't find it.

My understanding is that you wanted automatic suspend when no user is logged in after some period of time, which this answer has achieved, at least on my machine. There's somewhat another option. Once your log in screen appears, go to tty1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), login through there, and type `sudo shutdown -P +30`, which will shut down computer after 30 minutes, if no-one logs in. Downside of this , is that you have to cancel it once you get back to the machine, and if you forget, it will shut you down in the middle of work.

Let me know if this help. Cheers !

(PS: Dear moderators, please help me edit this answer, because when I posted text copies of the config file, the # signs would make all text bold, so I had to use pictures. If it's not to hard for you, please edit my answer, so that it also contains text copy of all the config files. Thank you!)

Comment: *Navigate to /etc/default and locate powernap file. `cd /etc/powernap` and `ls`.* - I've edited this to say `cd /etc/default`, surely that's what you meant, right?

Comment: @jco, nope. /etc/default has a file powernap, which is responsible for starting powernap service at boot. /etc/powernap is directory that has some config files for powernap itsel

Comment: @jco, if you don't mind, can you please edit that back to the way it was? I'm working on another question right now. Thanks!

Comment: @jco, nevermind, I fixed it already

Comment: Hm, it's still kind of confusing. Why do you say "navigate to /etc/default" and then immediately follow it by "`cd /etc/powernap`"? Both of these directories contain configuration, but they're separate. Not sure where I'm supposed to be.

Comment: @jco, I've edited it already. The /etc/default/powernap is the correct file. Probably , while i was typing this answer, it got messed up. I've had all sorts of funky things going on when trying to copy text from those files into the answer, before i gave up and posted pictures.

Comment: @jco, I've reviewed my answer. Now it's all correct. Like I already said, /ect/powernap has config files for powernap, but /etc/default has a file that enables powernap at boot. Basically

Comment: @jco, Sure, go ahead. I'm going to sleep , so you have 8 - 9 hours for all the editing ;) It's 4 am in my city

Comment: By the way, with text copies of the config files, you can post those use [formatting](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) - wrap them in a code block by placing four spaces before each line (and a newline before the first line), or by selecting it and pressing `<$>` on the bar above the edit answer box

Comment: @Wilf the problem probably is that they are trying to put the code in a list --- so they need to indent it 8 spaces, otherwise it is read as a normal paragraph continuation, or include it in triple-backtics. Last time I checked the `<$>` button is not smart enough in this case, you have to do it by hand.